# TF2 dedicated LAN server not found in game’s server browser

Tags: steam, technical-issues, team-fortress-2, source-engine

I’m running a dedicated Team Fortress 2 server on my LAN to which I can connect through my TF2 client’s console. However, it does not show in my TF2 client’s server browser. When I go to *Servers > LAN*, it just says “There are no servers running on your local network.”

What could be the problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: In `/home/tf2server/hlds/gameserver/orangebox`, put a file called `steam_appid.txt` whose sole contents are

```
440
```

Source: http://forums.srcds.com/viewtopic/18494

This also fixes « [Loadout unavailable on dedicated TF2 LAN server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82221/loadout-unavailable-on-dedicated-tf2-lan-server) ».

---

UPDATE: Found out there there are a couple more reasons why this can happen.

1. On the machine where you are running the Steam server, you also have the Steam *client* installed. **Solution:** Uninstall the Steam client. (Source: http://forums.srcds.com/viewpost/21999/118725#pid118725)
2. When you start the Steam server, you are specifying an IP address. **Solution:** Leave out the +ip parameter. (Source: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:oxKNEJJ8JvYJ:www.fusionnetwork.us/index.php/articles/general-tutorials/steam-fix-lan-server-not-showing-up-in-lan-server-browser/+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari)

Answer (score 0):

A server can also not appear in the public server browser if it has not been launched with a valid **Game Server Login Token** (GSLT). These appear as 32 character hexadecimal strings (16 bytes) and can be added to a server with the following command-line argument:

```
+sv_setsteamaccount [token]
```

You can also use the command `sv_setsteamaccount [token]` from the console or a config file.